# HttpContext becomes NULL in Tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, task, httpcontext

I create extension method for HttpContext. This method generates pdf files.

```
public static Task GeneratePdfTask(this HttpContext context, string path, int submissionId, string pdfName, Action<int, byte[]> postAction = null)
    {
        var local = context;
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            HttpContext.Current = local;
            SessionHelper.Set(SessionKey.IsPdfRendering, true);
            var pdfFile = new PdfGenerator().Generate(path, pdfName, submissionId);
            if (postAction != null && pdfFile != null)
            {
                postAction(submissionId, pdfFile);
            }
        });
    }
```

Sometimes this Session (`HttpContext.Current`) become NULL and i get exception. But don't know why. Is there some restriction of creating extensions for Session? Maybe there are some another solution how to safely use current Session?

Comment: Why `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run`? Are you working in .NET 4.0 or 4.5? 4.5 fixes several issues with configuring the HTTP context in asynchronous ASP.NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, .NET 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HTTP request objects concurrently from multiple threads so this question is moot. Pass the data you want to move across threads explicitly.

To explain what you are seeing: `HttpContext.Current` is dependent on the current thread (actually it's the logical call context). Don't set it to some value. You have now hijacked the `HttpContext.Current` of some innocent unrelated thread-pool thread. You might now find that different HTTP requests start to interact. Those are hard and nasty bugs to find.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ok, it seems to be solution (your advise) but please tell me if sending collection of cookies as parameter is good practise?

Comment: No because that object is not thread-safe. Almost none of the ASP.NET objects are. Only those that are documented thread-safe. Extract the necessary cookie information on the request thread and pass it around.